# Haskell QuickCheck generate random data for function with many input variables

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I have a function with the following type signature

```
rndListIndex :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
rndListIndex maxIdx r1 r2 = …
```

- the first input should be a value coming from a <strike>non-negative</strike> strictly positive integer
- the second and third input are required to be within the closed interval [0.0,1.0] otherwise the function makes no sense

the function has the property of

```
prop_alwaysLessThanMaxIdx idx r1 r2 = (rndListIndex idx r1 r2 <= idx)
```

how do I generate random data for `maxIdx` and `r1`,`r2` separately; I know of the function `choose`but do not know how to use it with more than one input variable.

For now I have tested the Property with fixed `idx`, which is not the way it should be tested.

Comment: Can the first value be 0 ?

Comment: Now that I think of it no it shouldn't - I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to use the [forAll](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/latest/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:forAll) function from QuickCheck. It has the following type:

```
forAll :: (Show a, Testable prop) 
       => Gen a           -- ^ The generator to use for generating values
       -> (a -> prop)     -- ^ A function which returns a testable property
       -> Property
```

`forAll` takes two arguments:

- The generator describes how to generate values. Examples of generators are [choose](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/latest/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:choose), [arbitrary](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/latest/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:arbitrary), [oneof](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/latest/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:oneof), ...
- The function tests the property for the given input. It must return a value that is an instance of `Testable`, for example another `Property`, `Bool` or a function.

Example of a nested forAll with the choose and elements generators:

```
-- This generates a Property p for all x's in the closed interval [1,3]
-- The property p in turn generates a property q for all y ∈ [4,5]
-- The property q is True if x < y.
prop_choose = forAll (choose (1,3)) $ \x ->
              forAll (elements [4,5]) $ \y -> x < y
```

For your test property, you can use forAll with choose for the second and third argument. 
For the first argument, there is the `Positive a` type in QuickCheck which can be used to generate arbitrary positive values of type a (It has an Arbitrary instance when a is a Num):

```
prop_alwayLessThanMaxIdx :: Positive Integer -> Property
prop_alwaysLessThanMaxIdx (Positive idx) = 
  forAll (choose (0,1)) $ \r1 ->
  forAll (choose (0,1)) $ \r2 ->
   (rndListIndex idx r1 r2) < idx
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest defining your own type that wraps `Double` and give it an `Arbitrary` instance that only generates numbers between 0 and 1. Something like:

```
import Test.QuickCheck
newtype UnitInterval = Unit Double deriving Show

instance Arbitrary UnitInterval where
  arbitrary = fmap Unit (choose (0, 1))
  shrink (Unit x) = [ Unit y | y <- shrink x, 0 <= y && y <= 1 ]
```

For generating `idx`, you can use QuickCheck's `Positive` modifier, as @bennoffs suggested (you will have to import `Test.QuickCheck.Modifiers`). This is similar to the `UnitInterval` type I defined above, but generates positive numbers instead of numbers between 0 and 1. Your property will then look like:

```
prop_alwaysLessThanMaxIdx (Positive idx) (Unit r1) (Unit r2) =
  rndListIndex idx r1 r2 <= idx
```